# Amazon CLI parallel deployment

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We build package that contains around 13 amazon lambda handlers [java].
Package is build using maven. When functions are deployed manually - we might upload same jar that includes dependencies and handlers multiple times specifying just different handler name. Functions share dependencies so this makes sense for us.

Can we run amazon CLI in parallel for faster deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you should consider writing a bash or python deployment script that calls the AWS CLI upload commands in parallel. Then, you should be able to deploy all thirteen of your Lambda handlers at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could upload the JAR to S3 once, and then have a Lambda function, triggered by that upload, written in JavaScript do async code deployments from S3 to your Lambda functions. For example, see the Lambda Auto-Deployer at [New Deployment Options for AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-deployment-options-for-aws-lambda/).

Comment: Makes sense. Then we perform upload only once. Jars are big 5-30 Mbs and as its same it will go to s3 and then "reused" when we point to it as s3 link rather than zip. Tnx!

Comment: Right, and if you think about it ... where does Lambda store the code that you upload for your Lambda functions (your ZIP file)? I don't know for sure, but I would guess that it is probably stored by the Lambda service in S3 (perhaps with a cache layer in front).